# why does set and get method in java persistence model should have the same name?

Tags: java, algorithm, hibernate, oop

I wonder why methods of get and set in java persistence model should have the same name after the word get and set.
As like this:

```
getCompanyName(){
}

setCompanyName(){
}
```

And I think this is not just in model, also in other configuration of get and set. Can anyone explain why? I really want to know.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: This has something to do with the JavaBean API and the ability for bean editors to be able to work. They basically strip off the get/set portion of the methods and display the remained as the property name, but if the method names are different, it would not work.  Also...it makes sense....

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

[Docs just recommending that format:](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence)

> This class(bean) uses standard JavaBean naming conventions for property setter and setter methods, as well as private visibility for the fields. Although this is the recommended design, it is not required. Hibernate can also access fields directly, the benefit of accessor methods is robustness for re factoring.

My possible reason's to follow that format:

1)First of all **Readability** of your code.

2)Secondly,no one provide a name `getCompanyName()` to get  `username`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note:

- A hibernate persistent entity is POJO.
- Set/Get method of a POJO enables a framework (like hibernate) to *introspect* the property of the [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) provided it follows a [Javabean Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).
- In absence of any standard convention, it will be difficult to create generalized frameworks which can read the properties of a POJO.